# convert double[][] to String [C#]

Tags: c#

```
double[] a = { 2.122, 3.665, 4.917 };
double[][] c = m_CO.Process(cc);

foreach(double d in c)
{
    lblText.Text = d.tostring();
}
```

and the result is `(system.Double[][])` Or `(Empty string)`

Comment: You should actually ask a question. You have shown what the result is, and some sample code that does not compile. What were you expecting it to be, and what is the actual code?

Comment: `foreach (double d in c)` won't compile

Comment: i want to display to value of the c in a label on the screen..and its return an empty string

Comment: Add the question in the original post for maximum visibility

Answer (score 1):

`ToString` on an object, unless overridden returns the type name of the object. In addition your `foreach` doesn't compile as each item in the 2d array is of type `double[]` and not `double`.

What you can do, using [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx) and Linq [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) is:

```
string result = string.Join(",", d.Select(i => string.Join(",", i)));
```

Or, if the separator is the same, with `SelectMany` as @Jakub Dabek suggested:

```
string result = string.Join(",", d.SelectMany(i => i));
```

For data:

```
double[][] d = new double[2][]
{
    new double[] {1,2},
    new double[] {3,4},
};
```

Will return: `"1,2,3,4"`

Comment: You can just do `string.Join(", ", d.SelectMany(t => t))`

Comment: @JakubDąbek - in case it is the same separator, true. Good suggestion. Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

`c` Is a [Jagged Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays). 
So try this:

```
 foreach (double[] da in c)
 {
     foreach (var d in da)
     {
          lblText.Text += d.ToString();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to run `.ToString()` on an array it will simply return its type.

If you want to convert this into a string you need to decide on the format. If I may suggest one:

```
double[] a = { 2.122, 3.665, 4.917 };
double[][] c = m_CO.Process(cc);

var usCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
// Using a list to build the string is more efficient than += every time
var tmpList = new List<string>();
foreach (var l1 in c) // l1 is double[]
{
    foreach (var l2 in l1) // l2 is double
    {
        // Specify en-US culture since many cultures use "," instead of "." for decimal separator
        tmpList.Add(l2.ToString(usCulture));
    }   
}
lblText.Text = string.Join(", " , tmpList);
tmpList.Clear();
```

Setting culture is not strictly necessary if program is only run under one culture. But coming from a culture with "," as separator I often encounter bugs related to this. You may also do `l2.ToString().Replace(",", ".")` of course.